# Weird formatting in Word 2010

Tags: windows, microsoft-word-2010, format, styles

A few months ago while writing a paper, I copied some paragraphs created in one computer to a different computer. I guess the formatting was different. Please see the following image:

[image]

I noticed that a strange formatting has also been imported. I thought it would go away when I select all and choose a format. But the problem did not go away. Now, when I am trying to finish the paper, the weird formatting still remains. Does anyone have any solution?

Also, how to make sure that when we copy something from a file with different **Styles**, we retain the destination style definitions?

**EDIT**

I would prefer a solution where I do not have to re-do the formatting manually.

Comment: The best solution I can think of without testing it myself is going to Styles >Clear All and then you can add the formatting and styles back in as per need. But, you said you don't want to redo the formatting. I have a VM up and running...is ther a way I can test it myself? I can for sure get a solution if I get to see your issue on my computer. That way I can play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to plaintext, restart the program, open the file and convert it back if needed.

Comment: But then I will have to do all formatting manually.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the **Format Painter** tool to quickly copy the format from the existing text in the doc to the new text pasted in?

[image]

Additionally, you can select all instances of text throughout the document with a particular type of formatting, and replace with a different style.

Also, when you copy rich (formatted) text to the clipboard and right-click, you can see different **Paste** options:

[image]

(From Left to Right, these are: **Use Destination Theme (H)**, **Keep Source Formatting (K)**, **Merge Formatting (M)** and **Keep Text Only (T)**.)

After pasting copied rich text you'll see a small hovering drop-down that again displays various **Paste** options:

[image]

(From Left to Right, these are: **Keep Source Formatting (K)**, **Merge Formatting (M)**, **Use Destination Styles (S)** and **Keep Text Only (T)**.)